# django queryset api - using values method with a list of fields

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I would like to make a query to a Django Model, but I do not know the fields to retrieve in advance. If I happen to know them and their number, I would do

```
MyModel.objects.values('field1', 'field2')
```

Indeed, I noticed that the `values` method takes optional positional arguments, *fields, as specified  in the API [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values).

Therefore, I thought of making a function, which takes `*fields` arguments and then using such args for my query. The wrapper would look like this:

```
def get_values(self, *fields):
   return MyModel.objects.values(fields)
```

However, I get an `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'` as the QuerySet API does not like my tuple. How could I work it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unpack the values :)

```
def get_values(self, *fields):
    return MyModel.objects.values(*fields)  # note the *
```

Otherwise it would be like you wrote

```
def get_values(self, *fields):
    return MyModel.objects.values(('field1', 'field2'))  # note the extra ()
```

... hence the `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'` because tuples do not have the `split` method!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the python **unpacking** feature:
The `*` operator can be used to send a list of params as positional arguments:

```
>>> fields = ['field1', 'fields2']
>>> MyModel.objects.values(*fields)
<MyModelQueryset [{'field1': 'foo1', 'field2': 'bar2'}, {'field1': 'foo1', 'field2': 'bar2'}, {'field1': 'foo1', 'field2': 'bar2'}]>
```